# Angular 2 Routing: Refresh page with parameter get "Fail to load resource" error

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-routing

I am learning Angular 2 from the official tutorial. I have just completed the latest routing tutorial. What keeps bothering me is that I am able to click through to the path till the detail level which is something like 'http://domainname:portnumber/crisis-center/11' where 'crisis-center' is a subpath and '11' is the id passed in a parameter.

what I found is if I navigate from the root path which is 'http://domainname:portnumber', then I could go through to the detail page without any trouble. But if I open a new window and directly visit the detail view page then it gives me error says 
[image]

which I believe is a failure of loading the loading 'js' files.

I have already had the base ulr tag

in the index.html page

```
 <html>

<head>



    <title>Tour of Heroes</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">


    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>

    <base href="/">


</head>

<body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</body>



</html>
```

and here is my path settings

```
import {RouterConfig} from '@angular/router';
import {CrisisDetailComponent} from './crisis-detail.component';
import {CrisisListComponent} from './crisis-list.component';
import {CrisisCenterComponent} from './crisis-center.component';
import {CrisisAdminComponent} from './crisis-admin.component';
import {AuthGuard} from '../auth.guard';

export const CrisisCenterRoutes: RouterConfig = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/crisis-center',
        terminal: true
    },

    {
        path: 'crisis-center',
        component: CrisisCenterComponent,
        children: [
            { path: 'admin', component: CrisisAdminComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
            { path: ':id', component: CrisisDetailComponent },
            { path: '', component: CrisisListComponent }



            ]
        }
]
```

Has anyone had similar issue and fixed it?

Thanks

Comment: I think that the actual root path of your application should be `http://domainname:portnumber/crisis-center`.  Your problem with `http://domainname` looks more like a server config issue (like proxypass) than an angular issue

Comment: sorry, that's a mistake in the editing. I will fix my question. It is with the port number

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you are missing one tiny line in your main index.html:

```
<base href="/">
```

as mentioned here https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#base-href

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, get distracted on other issues. You are actually correct. The reason that this was not working for me is that he base url declaration has to be earlier than importing the js files.

Comment: It'll be worth mentioning that it has to be placed above your script/style file in the `<head>`